# Running behave within Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-behave

I'd like to be able to run behave from the context menu within the PyDev project explorer (i.e. right click (on a feature file or directory) Run As- Behave and have it run the feature file (or files) once run the any errors in the output would take you to the line in the file it refers to.

Is this possible?

I have set behave up as an external tool, which works but it isn't great

Answer (score 0):

`PyDev` doesn't support `behave` directly but it does support `pytest`, so, my suggestion is using `behave` through `pytest` (you have to configure the test runner to be `pytest` -- see: https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html).

It seems that the related `pytest` plugin for running behave is: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-bdd/

Comment: It seems pytest-bdd is not a behave plugin but a completely different BDD implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (and PyDev) supports running other "External Tools" / Commands.
For behave, you just need to provide the definition to run a python script.

If anything fails, provide your own "run_behave.py" scripts that runs behave (much like the "behave script"). This also simplifies debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but as @jenisys noted, you have to make a tiny behave-runner like this (copied from the bin/behave command):

```
#!/path/to/your/env/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from behave.__main__ import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Run this, then modify the run / debug configuration with the behave command line arguments, and you're up and running (or debugging)!